# How do you define an upsert (if exists update else insert) using GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, upsert

I want to be able to send a single GraphQL document to add a record if none exist for the criteria specified, or update (partial or all non ident/non PK/non NK fields) an existing one if the criteria specified match an existing record.

I can do this a few ways in conventional SQL dialects and in ElasticSearch (update by query). But I do not see how it is supposed to be specified or described within graphql - or if it is even possible.

In the spec and on the web there are some examples for adding records that seem to require things that look like they are ["extra" or "nice to have"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51524027/16391) (like schema/type definitions) to be included in the document. The update examples often have field, argument, and variable names that do not match ([like Author.Id and authorId](https://medium.com/workflowgen/graphql-mutations-partial-updates-implementation-bff586bda989)), or are written using a non-GraphQL specific language like Javascript (same example page as "Author".) Doing this two stage operation from the end client does not seem like the correct approach either as only the target data store is going to know which is the correct operation to take.

There will not be a fixed predefined centralized schema for what I'm working on as it is a multi-tenant API and each tenant may have different definitions for a type (for example Tenant A has a Contract entity with 16 fields, but Tenant B has a type of the same name and intended function with 20 field. Both would share the same storage space for Contracts.

Is any what I'm asking about for even possible? If so can an example be shared?

Comment: no conditions/sorting/filtering etc in query possible ... why do you want to do that? ... why describing (in docs/specs) conditional mutation behaviour (dependent on passed variable set) is not enough ????????

Comment: @xadm - I want that because I dont want to update the last name field on all person records to be the same value, just the one. Because I cant find a coherent example anywhere,  I've asked if someone here can share an example of what the GraphQL document would look like to do a simple update that targets specific record(s) and if possible an upsert for the same..

Comment: I wrote how it can work .... `Last` alone doesn't pass validation step in resolver (not enough args for create, no ID arg for update) ... doesn't affect all records, no any DB actions fired, error thrown, where doubts? ... it's not query alone, it's query+variables+rules in resolver (and validator before action)

Comment: @xadm - I'm looking for a complete example of the graphQL payload sent over the network from a client to a server for either a full upsert or just an update. Giving me only bits and pieces of that does not help because I do not know the correct way to assemble them to make a request.

Comment: just try to build a PoC?

Comment: @xadm - if I cant compose the syntax for an update or upsert, how can I continue to build a PoC demonstrating how GraphQL can work for what we need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is... that you don't. There is no syntax or grammar for specifying or expressing an update behavior in the GraphQL other than the blanket idea of a resolver, for which you will have to entirely create your own syntax. For me that resolves to an incomplete query language.

Why this gap continues to exist is currently beyond me, but for the purposes of this question the answer is a disappointing "No" when it comes to updating.

Comment: Apples to oranges ... compare it to REST ... no syntax? probably never will be ... own syntax? not exactly ... input type for conditions from many vendors are similar, tree structured `where` (do some research) ... yes, it's not standarized (in specs) NOW but it doesn't stop people ... but it's up to you what this `where` means in your API ... suprisely they're creating similar solutions, adapted to environment/methodology and its possibilities (not sticking to older, well known solutions) ... sadly you don't feel it/don't see power in this freedom ... bad for you, not graphql

Comment: @xadm - I totally appreciate you sticking with this and owe you at _least_ one beer. I'm only trying to compare this against other object or data/type (aka graphs) query languages/functions and thats where I find this to be deficient. If you really think its not, then please share a complete example of the graphql payload that would be needed to send to a server that satisfies at least the update of the last name for an existing person record based on matching by employeecode (as outlined in the OP), without using any custom syntax.

Answer (score 1):

### [upsert-is-not-a-substitute-for-update](https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/core/mutations/upsert.html#upsert-is-not-a-substitute-for-update)

### ... then it can be a loose interpretation ...

`createItem` (name it `upsertItem` if you wish) mutation resolver can insert or update (BE, resolver implementation/storage/DB related decision) with **or without** strict/explicit input type definitions (required for create, optional for update)

... tenants can have different input types (fields amount) for the same mutation

... in wp-graphql (WordPress) it's even role based - different introspection results, different args for fields, different mutations available ... but it's from dynamic, non-persistent/stateless php character

You can just limit fields usage (per tenant) or type matching (required/not required) in some **validation 'layer' inside resolver or in middleware** just by throwing errors (when input doesn't match specific usage/tenant - f.e. return 'required error' for some field while all fields in type definitions are optional). When introspection query is blocked (on production) then it's just a documentation problem (not self-describing).

## update - example

> if the target entity to upsert is a Person with an ID, and First, and Last names, (ID and Last are required)

`ID` can't be required here ...

`UpsertPersonInput` with all (`ID`, `First`, `Last`) optional ...

**For create**: `upsertPerson( $input: UpsertPersonInput) {..` with variables required (by validation rules) for creation (`First: "some", Last: "Name"`)

... `ID` unknown here, created and returned as result

...no `ID` provided then assuming 'creation mode'

**For update**: query the same but when provided `input` variable with `ID` prop validation works in 'update mode' (at least one other variable - `input` prop - required, f.e. `Last` ... or other additional validation rules)

... while only `input.ID` prop provided > throw some "no required 'First' passed in input arg" (any field) Error ... as it would in separate update mutation and its input type.

Comment: thanks, if the target entity to upsert is a Person with an ID, and First, and Last names, (ID and Last are required),  and the update was to fix a misspelled last name and the field to match on was ID, what would the graphql actually it look like?  The sytax of this is where I'm struggling.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that ID and Last Name cannot be null on a stored record and should have given a different unique match field. In reality there would be the system "ID" field that we can ignore for now, and then some other combination fields that would make a record unique in its collection. In this example that could be an EmployeeCode field. In which case it _would_ be required as its not generated when null and would be the field to match on to determine update or insert.Whats the GraphQL actually look like for that operation? I appreciate the time you are taking to try to explain this

Comment: no any difference, still input type contains all possible fields as optional ... it's up to you how you construct validation rules for create and update modes (what subfield/prop existence determines mode, ... and for each of tenant - ignore or throws when passed not supported prop/subfield)

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase the problem - _GraphQL does not appear to have any kind of `WHERE` clause that I can use to identify the records to affect_    I dont actually think this is true, but I cant find an example of a GraphQL mutation that does an update thats using any kind of predicate filtering.

Comment: no any kind of sorting/filtering/etc. in specs ... not a query role to determine how resolver should work ... it's data-driven ... you CAN interpret (f.e. validate mode by) variables, you CAN resolve (work in create or update mode) by variables ... it's implementation detail ... you're defining what input data/args can mean ... WHERE clause to work on what? DB/file/remote service/datasource?

Comment: `UPDATE person SET LastName = 'Jones' WHERE EmployeeCode = 'ABC123'` is what I'm trying to find an equivalent for.   All I can find are examples for `INSERT person (FirstName, LastName, EmployeeCode) VALUES ('Mike', "Hones', 'ABC123')`

Comment: if there is no any support then **you have to construct it from input data** in resolver (when required) ... did you explored any graphql API with filtering/sorting/conditions? tons of them ... still, it hides implementation details

Answer (score 0):

There is no freedom when you have to supply all fields in an update or else they are set to NULL when using GraphQL.  There is no freedom when you have a table such as below:
TABLE1 ( ID NUMBER PK NOT NULL, FIRSTNAME VARCHAR2(20), LASTNAME VARCHAR2(20), COMPANY VARCHAR2(25), STATUS VARCHAR2(10) )

and in Oracle or any other database I could easily update the status of all records meeting conditions
UPDATE TABLE1
SET STATUS  = 'DONE'
WHERE COMPANY = 'XYZ CORP';

but in GraphQL I have to supply the ID in the update or get an error "ID required..." or having to include all the columns within the table
That is very inefficient.